# JBossEAP / Wildfly error renaming temporary file

Tags: eclipse, maven, jboss, wildfly

for the past several days I've been experiencing this error, while publishing to either JBoss EAP 6.3 or Wildfly 8.2 from Eclipse.

[image]

```
Error renaming D:\Servers\wildfly-8.2.0.Final\standalone\tmp\tmp9064011157118650757.jar 
to D:\Servers\wildfly-8.2.0.Final\standalone\deployments\BusinessService.war\WEB-INF\lib\spring-web-4.2.3.RELEASE.jar.

This may be caused by incorrect file permissions, or your server's temporary deploy 
directory may be on a different filesystem than the final destination. You may adjust 
these settings in the server editor.
```

The problem occurs when I "Add and Remove..." projects from the server, then try to publish them, so the server can start.

I've experienced this issue on two different machines (home (Wildfly) and work (JBoss EAP)).

I'm using:

- Windows 7 / 10
- Eclipse Mars / Luna
- JBoss Tools plugin 4.3 / 4.2
- JDK 1.8.0.66 / 1.8.0.65
- Maven

Building with maven from Eclipse and from the command line makes no difference. The server is configured to deploy projects as compressed archives. On both machines my user has administrator rights and has full rights on the server directory.

So far I've tried:

- recreating the server multiple times with different configurations
- using a newly created workspace
- reinstalling JBoss Tools
- reinstalling Eclipse
- using different JDK versions

I'm really at a loss here and I don't know how to proceed in resolving this issue. Please help.

Comment: "For the past several days...". Do you mean by that, that you haven't experienced this problem before for the same set of actions you took? Also, are there any recent things you changed in settings or have there been recent changes in your environment?

Comment: I did manage to do work in this environment for several weeks by deploying my wars to JBoss from maven and just starting the server from Eclipse. I needed to use the Eclipse debugger though and for it to work the projects had to be added to the server by "Add and Remove..." and then the problem started. Nothing has been changed or added to the server settings or the environment. Then I decided to try this at home as well and I managed to reproduce the problem quite easily by just deploying a very simple and minimal Spring Boot application.

Comment: You can remote debug JBoss/WildFly. That's what I always do. You can enable that in eg JBoss 7 by editing `bin\standalone.conf.bat` and uncomment the proper line, and in Eclipse make a new Debug Configuration for `Remote Java Application` (specify the port you configured in previous step). Then when you want to debug you simply start that new Debug entry you created. I've always been against running this directly in Eclipse, it has resulted in unexpected problems for me.

Comment: @DDV I'm still encountering this problem. Did you manage to fix it? I would really appreciate a solution.

Comment: @GGrec I'm sorry, I haven't found any reliable and stable solution to this problem, I stopped using this functionality altogether and I deploy manually when working with Wildfly/EAP. You can read more about the issue at the jboss tools forums - [here](https://developer.jboss.org/message/949051#949051)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are using Windows, the path could get too long and can cause this error. A simple fix is to move WildFly closer to the root.

Comment: your solution worked for me. Ideally I would like to switch to another IDE, because Eclipse is so full of time wasting and frustrating bugs and quirks like this one, but mysteriously some companies are still using it.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem and solved it like this:

First of all, stop Server (Servers->WildFly(rigth click)->Stop), than clean. So you can run server again.

Answer (score 0):

I had this problem several times in my new windows 10 machine that my employer gave me. Since I did not have admin rights it was a hectic process to troubleshoot this issue. Simple fix would be moving JBOSS_HOME closer to root. However, you need to do a proper restart of your eclipse. I rather recommend a complete restart of your computer because after all you are going to change JBOSS_HOME in windows environmental variables.

Answer (score 0):

This is related to permissions issue on wildfly folder. Allow full control to the wildfly folder.

https://issues.jboss.org/browse/JBIDE-18697

Answer (score 0):

I have moved the wildfly home to reduce the overall path length, and also removed any non-alphanumeric characters from the folder name (like "-"  and "." ) . This worked for me, everything else (removing tmp, deployment, rebooting wildfly, rebooting eclipse, rebooting computer) failed.
I also suspect that the issue was stemming from running Wildfly from a ConEmu and/or git bash shell. Running from a plain CMD shell seems more robust.

Answer (score 0):

I also got stuck with the same problem. I tried the below steps and it worked:

1. Clear the deployments and tmp folder in standalone folder in wildfly folder.
2. Delete the server and again add the server
3. Make a build of the project and start the server after successful build.

Answer (score 0):

This is a terribly annoying error that either the Eclipse team or Redhat need to fix.

The solution is to close Eclipse, right click on the icon -> Run As Administrator.  This solved it for me.